# CSS: Two problems with Style axis of bus stops

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

[Sorry for my bad English]

I have to show route of bus.

- Stops should be grouped by city name.
- Vertical line should connect all stops circles.

The result should be like this picture.

[image: sample]

This is my trying. https://jsfiddle.net/xgL98h0w/2/
(The code is React, but it doesn't matter)

I have two problems with it:

1. City names (depend on their length) are not aligned with the border. For example, see the "Long City Name".
2. I don't know how to connect the circles with vertical line. I tried to add `::after` pseudo-element for each circle, but i don't success to make it work. Given that the circles has `flex` display, the `::after` pseudo-element doesn't aligned propertly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's something wrong with your jsfiddle link. It brings up a generic React starter app, not your specific code.

Comment: @kshetline, Sorry! I fixed the link.

Comment: @dacre-denny, may you can help me againg...

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle. I've been playing with the CSS, trying to figure out how to rotate variable-width and then position it consistently, and haven't found a solution. The width of the text affects how far the rotated version moves to the right, and I can't find a CSS way to express the concept of repositioning the rotated result to the same fixed position *after* the rotation. CSS seems to position first, then rotate after. If you made all of the city labels the same width (what becomes their height after they're rotated), that would probably (as a compromise) fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank's for the question!**

There was aligned name of cities (depend on their length) by the border of the block.

Was connected the circles with vertical line with pseudo-element `::after`. Also `::after` pseudo-element was aligned properly.

**There you are!**

https://jsfiddle.net/Kostandy/yvqb5rso/153/

Hope it will be useful for You!

Comment: It's not even my question, but I was still trying to work out the label part of this for myself. I just came up with a solution moments ago, but I didn't know about the CSS `writing-mode` property, which definitely makes this easier. My solution (of just the label part) looks like this: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/xxKBxYe